# Get the bit depth or the color space of a mp4 file in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, color-space, hdr

I'm currently working on a video player on Android. The video player should support 8 bit content and 10 bit content. Because the flow in the app is different, I need to know before playing the video if the content is 10-bit BT2020. I've tried `MediaMetadataRetriever` but there is no information about the bit depth, color space, color primaries, transfer characteristics etc. Also, I got the same result using this project: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.

Is there a way to get some more information about the color space or bit depth in Android? Something similar to MediaInfo tool. https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found out that I can use `MediaExtractor` then get the information that I needed from a `MediaFormat` object created with `extractor.getTrackFormat(trackIndex)`. For HDR10 I check the color standard and the transfer function.

```
mediaFormat.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_STANDARD)
) {
    if (mediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_TRANSFER) == MediaFormat.COLOR_TRANSFER_ST2084
        && mediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_STANDARD) == MediaFormat.COLOR_STANDARD_BT2020
    ) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the tranfer function, actually.